# How to transfer a task in Synergy

Tags: cm-synergy

How do I transfer a task to another user in CM Synergy?

I have a task assigned to me, but I need to transfer it to another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer a task, right click on the task and go to properties.  In the Properties dialog box, select the resolver that is desired.